# Writing Data to Partitioned Parquet File Using R

Tags: r, parquet, apache-arrow

I am using `Arrow` package in `R` to work with `parquet` files. I prepared the dataset as `DataTable`, and I have the local folder e.g. `D:\Events\` How can I write this `DataTable` object as `parquet` into that folder, and specify partitioning columns "Device" and "Month"

Hint:
No `spark` cluster is setup, I am testing on my local machine

Comment: Could you share some code you've tried? If https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html#writing-datasets-1 is incomplete please let us know.

To be clear, Spark is not required to use `arrow`.

Comment: @NealRichardson I used the following statements: ```#Save the result into parquet files
parquet_path <- "D:\\Events\\Events.parquet"        
write_parquet(dt_events, parquet_path)```

Comment: @NealRichardson how can I add partitioning to above code?

Comment: The link to the dataset writing vignette shows how to add partitioning using group_by. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/write_dataset.html may also be useful for you.